# Präteritum im Norden – Verben

Tags: tense, preterite

Wird das Verb „schreiben“ häufig im gesprochenen Sprachgebrauch im Präteritum (also schrieb) verwendet? Ich meine ebenfalls zum Simsen.

Comment: Wie dürfen wir den letzten Satz Deiner Frage verstehen?

Answer (score 3):

Im "gesprochenen Sprachgebrauch", also der Umgangssprache, wird Präteritum ungeachtet des spezifischen Verbs ausgesprochen selten verwendet. Im Allgemeinen verwenden auch wir Norddeutschen eher Perfekt, wenn wir über die Vergangenheit reden.

Siehe zum Bsp. [diesen Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-imperfekt-praeteritum-a-344448.html), der meine persönliche Erfahrung bestätigt.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass das eher auf jeweiligen Dialekt ankommt. Nämlich sah ich in Untertiteln: Als er aus dem Untersuchungszimmer rausging, wurde er ohnmächtig. Oder auch Als ich eine Pizza aß, rief mich mein Freund an.

Comment: Ich denke nicht, dass Leute tatsächlich in ihrer Umgangssprache so sprechen (und ich habe sowohl in Hamburg als auch in München gelebt). Man würde eher so etwas sagen: "Neulich hab' ich 'ne Pizza gegessen. Da hat mein Freund angerufen." Oder: "Als er aus dem Untersuchungszimmer rausgegangen ist, wurde er ohnmächtig."

Comment: Jugendliche müssen aber nicht immer Umgangssprache verwenden.

Comment: Ich habe keine Ahnung wie Jugendliche heute sprechen. Aus dem Alter bin ich lange raus. Allerdings habe ich eher nicht den Eindruck, dass die Hochsprache, abgesehen von besonderen Anlässen und in der Schule, von ihnen viel verwendet wird. Das Gegenteil ist vermutlich der Fall. Das Fernsehen, und noch weniger die Untertitel, kann hier wohl kaum als Maßstab herhalten.

Comment: Herr Sick schreibt in seinem Zwiebelfisch: *»Deshalb nennt man das Perfekt auf Deutsch auch "vollendete Gegenwart".«* Diese Aussage ist falsch (und leider typisch für Deutsche). Richtig wäre: *»Deshalb nennt man das Perfekt **in Deutschland** auch "vollendete Gegenwart".«* Denn in Österreich (genauer: im österreichischen Deutsch, das ja auch ein standardisiertes Deutsch ist) gibt es keine *»vollendete Gegenwart«.* Das Perfekt heißt bei uns *»Vergangenheit«* und hat keinen Bezug zur Gegenwart. (Das Präteritum heißt *»Mitvergangenheit«.*) ...

Comment: ... Die unterschiedliche Verwendung dieser Vergangenheitsformen ist der größte und eklatanteste Unterschied zwischen österreichischem und deutschem Deutsch.

Comment: @Damian: Untertitel müssen kurz sein, damit sie schnell verarbeitet werden können. Präteritum ist kürzer als Perfekt. Aber: 'gehen' wird nach meiner Erfahrung relativ häufig im Präteritum gebraucht, 'wurde' ist sehr häufig. 'Essen' im Präteritum (aß) dürfte in gesprochener Sprache eine Rarität sein, 'rief ... an' könnte ich mir kontextabhängig vorstellen, ich selbst würde aber auch bei 'anrufen' das Perfekt bevorzugen.

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: Das ist falsch, denn die Grenze für dieses Phänomen liegt irgendwo im Fränkischen, nicht bei Salzburg.

Comment: @Janka: Die Schüler in Passau hören in der Schule nie etwas von einer *Mitvergangenheit*. Jene aus dem 13 km entfernten Schärding aber sehr wohl, wie auch in Kufstein, wo die Schüler jedoch nichts von einer vollendeten Gegenwart erfahren. 5 km von Kufstein entfernt, in Kiefersfelden, bringt man den Schülern aber die vollende Gegenwart sehr wohl bei, sagt ihnen aber nichts von der Mitvergangenheit. Da bin ich aber nicht irgendwo im Fränkischen, sondern ganz exakt an der Staatsgrenze.

Comment: Ich habe als Schüler **niemals** etwas von einer "vollendeten Gegenwart" erfahren, stattdessen von *Mitvergangenheit* und *Vergangenheit*. Tatort: Braunschweiger Land. Das Perfekt als Gegenwartstempus war folglich auch das, was beim Englischlernen die meisten Schüler verwirrte.

Answer (score 2):

Das Präteritum von "schreiben" wird in der Alltagssprache auch in Norddeutschland nur sehr selten verwendet. Sätze wie "Ich schrieb dir doch schon gestern, dass..." oder "Er schrieb mir, dass..." klingen ungewöhnlich und sind wenig verbreitet. In SMS kann ich es mir kaum vorstellen.

Stattdessen wird auch in Norddeutschland meistens das Perfekt verwendet: "Ich habe dir doch schon gestern geschrieben, dass...".

In rein narrativen Texten wird Präteritum aber durchaus verwendet. Wenn man ein also Märchen erzählt oder eine lange zurückliegende Handlung wiedergibt, dann passt auch "schrieb".

Answer (score 0):

Ich wohne im sogenannten Westen (Essen, Ruhrgebiet), ich würde 'schrieb' nicht so verwenden, höchstens als Substantiv (*der Schrieb* = umgangssprachlich für *der Brief*).

Answer (score 0):

Präteritum - egal welches, wird kaum im deutschen, mündlichen Sprachgebrauch verwendet, dort verwendet man eher das Perfekt. Präteritum wird überwiegend im schriftlichen Srachgebrauch verwendet.
Eine Ausnahme aber bildet beispielsweise das Verb "sein"; hier werden Perfekt und Präteritum, je nach Region, weitestgehend gleichwertig verwendet. (z.B "Ich war beim Bäcker/ Ich bin beim Bäcker gewesen")

Answer (score 0):

Ich lebe nähe Hannover und ich nutze Präteritum sehr häufig und auch Leute aus meinem Umkreis. Ich glaube, viele bemerken nicht, wie oft sie den verwenden, denn dass er ja so selten im sprachlichen Gebrauch sein solle scheint mir absurd. Im Süden ist das definitiv so, doch im Norden ist er um einiges häufiger im Gebrauch. Zwar nicht jedes Verb. Ich würde nur selten "schrieb" oder "trank" sagen, aber die meisten Verben schon. Jeder würde doch z.b. "dachte" oder "ging" sagen